# Ubuntu open ports of client

Tags: serial-port

I am working with a server on a VM with 4 clients.I want to know which ports are open on which of my client. I have the IP of every one of my client but what statement should I use in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nmap`

`nmap -PN your_ip_address`

For more help you can check the man page of the `nmap`